# How can I use SMS broadcast receiver in for different Activity

Tags: android

I have SMS broadcast Receiver Activity. I am using it for one screen(Monitor).
I also want to use this for another screen(Registration). I have different activities for Monitor and Registration. How can I use this?
Currently I am able to use the BroadcastRecevier only for Registration screen

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{


    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Bundle bundle=intent.getExtras();

        Object[] messages=(Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] sms=new SmsMessage[messages.length];

        for(int n=0;n<messages.length;n++){
            sms[n]=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) messages[n]);
        }

        for(SmsMessage msg:sms){

//          RegActivity.updateMessageBox(msg.getMessageBody());
            MonitorMenu.updateMessageBox(msg.getMessageBody());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Broadcast Receiver will called only when any msg is broadcasted so your receiver will be called when sms will be received.. so whenever your receiver is called save the data in somewhere and use it wherever you want to use..

Comment: I want to use this data between two activities. How can I find out which screen is been shown on the screen

Comment: May be you can check which activity is currently running(activity on the top of stack). Activity Manager provide method for that